# Which List will work fast in large list of data such as images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Which List will work fast in a large list of data such as images? Flat list or VirtualizedList? which list should I use for a scalable mobile app built in react native? which will work faster in a large list of data like images I tried both and I feel the same because my device is fast but what about 2-4-6-8 gb ram of phones? which will work faster technically both new phones and old phones?

What should I use in my use case? my use case is to display images like Facebook posts what can be a better option for me?

Answer (score 0):

There're no advantages to one on other each one used for a purpose:

**1- FlatList:**

A performant interface for rendering basic, flat lists and have a lot of optimization to make it work on big data like `initialNumToRender`

**2- VirtualizedList:**

This should only really be used if you need more flexibility than FlatList provides, e.g. for use with immutable data instead of plain arrays.

In your case, FlatList can do the job without any performance disadvantages.

Hope this will help you.

Source: [React Native Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist).

Comment: i am fetching post image from backend database so will flatlist will do  best?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer VirtualizedList only gives you more flexibility but on the performance side, they are the same.